# Is it possible to use object expressions for AsyncTask declaration/initialization using Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, kotlin

What I want to do is:

```
val myTask = object: AsyncTask<Unit,Unit,Unit>() {
   {...}
}
myTask.execute()
```

Or even shorter:

```
(object : AsyncTask<Unit,Unit,Unit>() {
   {...}
}).execute()
```

But it gives me **"This AsyncTask class should be static or leaks might occur (...)"**. And it seems that I can't subclass and instantiate AsyncTask like I can do with others abstract classes. It seems that I have to write all the:

```
class BlaBla: AsyncTask<Unit,Unit,Unit>() {
   {...}
}
BlaBla().execute()
```

Why?

Comment: Please guys, if there is something wrong with my question, tell me what it is. I'm only getting downvoted but I don't understand why.

Comment: It seems that nobody is interested in helping you, well, let's see if I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you create an anonymous inner class or a lambda inside the method of a class, it has a reference to its enclosing class. So if you create an inline object, it will be able to access the enclosing class as `this@MainActivity`, and that's what causes this trouble.

What you say however would be possible if you wrote something like this (code heavily inspired by the [LruCache in android-ktx](https://github.com/android/android-ktx/blob/8edebc92394e4478145f0369786f6c7db25f2d13/src/main/java/androidx/core/util/LruCache.kt)):

```
inline fun executeTask(crossinline backgroundTask: () -> Unit): AsyncTask<Unit, Unit, Unit> =
    executeTask<Unit, Unit, Unit>(
        backgroundTask = { backgroundTask() },
        postExecute = {}
    )

inline fun executeTask(
    crossinline backgroundTask: () -> Unit,
    crossinline onPostExecute: () -> Unit = {}
): AsyncTask<Unit, Unit, Unit> =
    executeTask<Unit, Unit, Unit>(
        backgroundTask = { backgroundTask() },
        postExecute = { onPostExecute() }
    )

inline fun <Params, Progress, Result> executeTask(
    vararg params: Params,
    crossinline backgroundTask: (Array<out Params>) -> Result, //todo: publish progress needs this to have AsyncTask receiver 
    crossinline preExecute: () -> Unit = {},
    crossinline postExecute: (Result) -> Unit = {},
    crossinline progressUpdate: (Array<out Progress>) -> Unit = {},
    crossinline onCancel: (Result?) -> Unit = {}
): AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> = object : AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Params): Result = backgroundTask(params)

        override fun onPreExecute() = preExecute()

        override fun onPostExecute(result: Result) = postExecute(result)

        override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: Progress) = progressUpdate(values)

        override fun onCancelled(result: Result?) = onCancel(result)
    }.execute(*params)
```

Which would let you do something like:

```
executeTask(
    backgroundTask = { ... },
    onPostExecute = { ... }
)
```

But you should **still not use this in an Activity directly**, because of what I mentioned above: that the object created in `executeTask` method would create an async task that can outlive the activity.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It helped me. Now I get it, and now I'm getting to know memory, lifecycle and references better. However, can you help me with one more thing? Is it totally safe if I create my AsyncTask inside the Activity's class and use a WeakReference to reach it, and then check if the reference points to null before I try reaching the Activity or its properties inside the doInBackground() or onPostExecute() of the Task? Oh, and will the Task still exist and will it continue being executed after the Activity is destroyed?

Comment: I tend to tell people and stand by that using a weak reference in an AsyncTask is a hack, and you should execute the task in something that you keep alive using onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance, or in a retained fragment (which is cool because it has `getActivity` method which returns the new activity if the task took longer and the fragment got attached to a new activity) - but if you check Android Architecture Components's ViewModel, it handles all this stuff internally, survives config change. So the safest way to do this is in a LiveData that is in a ViewModel.

Comment: The task exists even after the Activity is destroyed, yes. It can be canceled but the cancelation is something you would manually need to handle in `doInBackground`. I have to change it to `AsyncTask.(Params)`for that. But I'll have to verify later if I need to change anything in the code to add the receiver param.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, the documentation: [The Async Task](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2166868&seqNum=3)

> AsyncTask

At its core, the AsyncTask is an abstract class that you extend and that provides the basic framework for a time-consuming asynchronous task.

The best way to describe the AsyncTask is to call it a working thread sandwich.

> An object is a singleton. You do not need to create an instance to use it.
>
> A class needs to be instantiated or extends to be used

Look this: [Difference between a class and object in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44255946/difference-between-a-class-and-object-in-kotlin)

## In summary ... convert AsyncTask to object is incorrect