# Android Performance Comparison: Object vs Class in Kotlin

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, android-memory

I want to know the performance comparison when using function inside a Class and inside an Object in Kotlin. As far as I know, Object was singleton and Class wasn't.

**For Example**

```
Object engine {
   fun doSomethingOften(){
   // Here the function which oftenly called
   }

   fun doSomethingRare(){
   // Here the function which rarely called
   }
}
```

**VS**

```
Class engine {
   fun doSomethingOften(){
   // Here the function which oftenly called
   }

   fun doSomethingRare(){
   // Here the function which rarely called
   }
}
```

Which was better in memory management?

Does using Class can make memory used lower because it can be cleaned using Garbage Collector? Or it doesn't?

Can someone help me about this?

Comment: Well if there is possible to using object is good then class in Kotlin! But don't ask this type of question in stack overflow like difference between and/or which is best!!

Comment: @NickBapu Well, where should I ask this type of question? I want to know about best practice for that, and I think this question can have a certain answer which referred from documentation or something I didn't know.

Comment: Ask this type of question in [Quora](https://www.quora.com/) or in other sites.

Answer (score 0):

> Does using Class can make memory used lower because it can be cleaned
>   using Garbage Collector? Or it doesn't?

Objects are very similar to classes. If you just want some utility functions then it makes sense to use `object` or just top-level functions because `object` will be initialized only once while if you are using a `class`, whenever you want to use any function you will have to initialize it which is certainly not a good practice at all and bad for performance.

To read more about the difference between these two, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47706264/5699956)