# Dagger Issue - Generate useCase has error

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger

i created my useCase and setup input and output and then provide it on module and everything works fine.

```
class GetProfileUseCase constructor(
    private val repository: Repository,
    defaultDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) : SuspendUseCase<Request, ResultEntity<Response>>(defaultDispatcher) {

    override suspend fun execute(parameters: Request): ResultEntity<Response> {
        return repository.getProfile(parameters)
    }
}
```

and here is my data class

```
sealed class GetProfile : Serializable {

    data class Request(
        val nothing: Nothing? = null
    ) : GetProfile()

    data class Response(
        val user: User? = User()
    ) : GetProfile()
}
```

because there is no parameter in Request class i tried changed it to :

```
object Request
```

but when build it IDE error :

error: method create in class ViewModel_Factory cannot be applied to given types;

and here is my view model :

```
class ViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getProfileUseCase: GetProfileUseCase
) : BaseViewModel()
```

i don't know why it happen and dagger couldn't generate classes !!!

it works without no error when set Request as data class but crash when make it object class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> because there is no parameter in Request class i tried changed it to :
> object Request

You seem to think an `object` is same as a `class` with a single no parameter `constructor`, which is not true. For complete understanding I encourage you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44255946/difference-between-a-class-and-object-in-kotlin) thread.
However I will try to provide a brief explanation as to why your code doesn't work

When you do `object Request`, it makes `Request` a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), meaning you can no longer create its `instances` using `val instance = Request()`, reason being that `constructor` of `Request` is marked private by kotlin compiler.

so when your code(`dagger`) tries to inject `Request` using `new Request()`, it gives you error.